# Updating rooted android through OxygenOS Updater

Tags: updates, magisk, oxygenos

Forum,

I am trying to update my rooted OnePlus6 from Oxygen `10.3.9` to `10.3.11`. For this I am trying to use the OxygenOS updater app, which is a handy software updating utility tool. When doing this, I can select an option *"Keep my device rooted"*. Under this option the following description is provided: *"When you select this option, you may specify a root package which will be installed after the update is installed. This ensures that your device stays rooted. Please note that this root package must be compatible with the NEW OxygenOS version you are going to install!*

I have always used magisk to root my phone. I would like to keep it rooted, so therefore I was thinking to provide `Magisk-23.0.zip` as a root package.

My question is: **How do I know whether magisk 23.0 is compatible with OxygenOS 10.3.11?**

Comment: Install Magisk Manager in your current OS. The preferred way of installing Magisk as recommended by its developer is to load the stock boot image in the app so that it can be patched, and then flash that patched boot image. In Magisk Manager, tap on Install, Select and Patch a File -> load the boot image from to-be-installed OS (10.3.11 in this case) and see if Magisk successfully patches it or not. That's how you know whether Magisk would work with target boot image or not.

Comment: Thanks. Is this also the easiest way to update a rooted phone?

Comment: That said, everything you're doing seems overkill to me personally. Just use Settings app to update the System. It would remove your recovery and Magisk patches of course, but *that's okay*. This way, you would have a pristine working new OS build that you can manipulate without hiccups. Once update is successful, just use fastboot to flash Magisk patched boot image `fastboot flash boot magisk-patched-boot.img`. Reboot, and your device would have new OS build with root access.

Comment: Just 3-4 days ago I moved from 10.3.5 to 10.3.11 following the process I suggested.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Am a bit new to rooting. The method with the app I just described unrooted my phone, So am now in the process of re-rooting it. Next time I will upgrade using your method. Related to this I have two small questions

1. where did you find the 10.3.11 boot image? I cannot find it on the official oneplus website, 2. Can I also use TWRP to flash this image? Not used to flashing images that reside on phone by using fastboot

Comment: Do some backup to PC although its not needed. You can delete it afterwards

Comment: @Psychotechnopath I didn't find need to find boot image. I applied the whole OTA using Settings app's default System update functionality. Once I confirmed that new build was working fine I downloaded twrp image, booted into it using fastboot, then copied (using `dd`) boot partition into a file (boot.img). That boot.img is the boot image I needed. // Yes, you can flash the boot image using TWRP.